# How can I serve VBS and other file types as plain text from a Subversion repository (Apache)?

Tags: svn, text, apache2, mime-types, apache-config

I just want to browse my Subversion code repositories and view files.  Some of the file types, like .VBS, prompt me to open or save the file, but I just want to view it in the browser as plain text.  Can Apache's httpd.conf file be modified to do this?  I don't think it would be changed on the client (IE7) because then it would work the same on all sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the mime type of all your vbs files to text/plain by doing this in the root of your working copy:

```
svn propset --recursive svn:mime-type text/plain *.vbs
```

and then commit the changes. Explanation from the svn book on [repository browsing](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing):

> To make this happen, you need only to
>   make sure that your files have the
>   proper svn:mime-type set. We discuss
>   this in more detail in [the section
>   called “File Content Type”](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.file-portability.html#svn.advanced.props.special.mime-type), and you
>   can even configure your client to
>   automatically attach proper
>   svn:mime-type properties to files
>   entering the repository for the first
>   time; see [the section called
>   “Automatic Property Setting”](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).
>
> So in our example, if one were to set
>   the svn:mime-type property to
>   text/html on file foo.html, Apache
>   would properly tell your web browser
>   to render the file as HTML. One could
>   also attach proper image/* MIME-type
>   properties to image files and
>   ultimately get an entire web site to
>   be viewable directly from a
>   repository!

Comment: Thanks, I'll be trying this Monday.  It seems better to do it through SVN than the Apache conf, although both would work.  I tried to search for how to do this, but couldn't get good key words to nail down an answer.  Looks like I need to go straight to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following into your httpd.conf

```
<IfModule mime_module>
AddType text/plain .vbs
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do I add additional types with spaces or comma separation?  
Like AddType text/plain .vbs ps1 css

Comment: Spaces. The documentation on the topic, for Apache 2.2: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype